# serverPrefetch Mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, ssr, server-side-rendering

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто делал mixin для нового serverPrefetch, который во Vue 2.6?
Несколько дней уже пытаюсь написать реализацию -- пока не выходит.
Смысл в том, чтобы не дублировать логику в mounted, вотчерах и updated, а просто воспользоваться mixin'ом